# Cannot modify headers when adding a new user

Tags: 7, users, bootstrap-theme

I periodically get an error in my drupal log that I believe is generated when a user is modifying or creating an account.
Today, when adding an account as an admin, I finally saw it on the screen:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at includes/common.inc:2777) in includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1486.

Here is the code referenced in the error, line 1486 is the server protocol:

```
foreach ($headers as $name_lower => $value) {
    if ($name_lower == 'status') {
      header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' ' . $value);
    }
    // Skip headers that have been unset.
    elseif ($value !== FALSE) {
      header($header_names[$name_lower] . ': ' . $value);
    }
```

I am using a bootstrap theme for the main part of the site, however, this is the admin theme which uses Garland. All users see the admin theme when editing their account. To my knowledge, there is no ending php tag being used somewhere.

[image]

Note: I understand that this question has been asked numerous times but I am not satisfied with the level of detail and wanted to get down to something more specific for my instance.

Drupal 7.59.

Comment: In general like this warning caused by closing PHP tag at the end of php file `?>` , see if you add some code lately has  closing PHP tag !

Comment: Thank you. I mentioned that I already looked for this. I typically do not write any php code and stick to well developed contribs.

Comment: You are welcome, try to enable `OUTPUT_BUFFER` set it to on in your `php.ini` and see some posts say that the cause of this issue my be the `OUTPUT_BUFFER` [here is an article how to enable it](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php.ini-directives/php-output_buffering-directive)